# How to check if ASP:TextBox control it has value in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to check some **Textbox** control if they have value do some addition else do assignment, I used the **JQuery** script below it didn't work for me.

The idea is on key up it should call the JQuery Function to check if TextBox797 have value then sum up the value of TextBox651 and TextBox797 else replace the value of TextBox797 with value of TextBox651. it not showing any result

this is the JQ script i have in the Function

```js
if ($('#<%=TextBox797.ClientID%>').val() != "" 
     && $('#<%=TextBox797.ClientID%>').val() >= 0) {

  document.getElementById('<%=TextBox797.ClientID%>').value = 
          parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox797.ClientID%>').value) + 
          parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox651.ClientID%>').value);

} else {

  document.getElementById('<%=TextBox797.ClientID%>').value = 
          parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox651.ClientID%>').value);

}
```

Please kindly show me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Any errors in the console? Or it runs but does the wrong thing - if so, what? Also, where is the above code called from? Please [edit] your question to provide those details. (And if you're using jQuery anyway, why mix in the longer `document.getElementById()` calls instead of `$()`?)

Comment: Many Thanks Tan, first of all i am new to JQuery so i have textbox where i call the JS function, the complete code is some like this  <ASP:TextBox id="TextBox651" runAt="server" onKeyUp="CheckTxt" /> i still have TextBox797 under so the idea is onKeyUp  TextBox651 will check TextBox797 if it have value do addition else replace it content

Comment: You need to use `onKeyUp="CheckTxt()`. Looking at your comment above that is. You forget the `()`.

Comment: Many thanks to all, i was able to solve the problem by assigning the value of the textbox to a variable then check the text box.